# what does pipe number in parameter list mean in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning angular and following the official angular [docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-heroservicedeletehero).
One of the methods threw me off and I would like to understand what is happening.

`deleteHero(hero: Hero | number): Observable<Hero> {
    const id = typeof hero === 'number' ? hero : hero.id;
    const url = ${this.heroesUrl}/${id};`

What does the pipe number in the parameter list supposed to do?
(I checked and there is no number pipe by default that ships with angular.)

why is `const id = type of hero === number ? hero : hero.id`.
Why isn't it just `const id = hero.id`?

Unfortunately the docs did not explain this in the sections that followed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a pipe operator (which can only be used inside HTML templates), but a TypeScript's way of annotating the function argument's type.

```
deleteHero(hero: Hero | number)
```

This means that the function accepts one argument whose type is either `Hero` or `number`. In the context of the tutorial, a hero can be deleted by providing a hero reference or a hero ID - that's why this is checked in the beginning of the function's body.

Comment: Thank for the response! I was only then curious why is the return type from a delete action Observable<Hero> why isn’t it Ovservable<any>? We were deleting the hero we shouldn’t be expecting a hero back??

Answer (score 0):

here `number` isn't pipe, it means that hero parameter can be of type `Hero` or `number`, `|` means `OR` in your example, 
about second question, it checks for type number, because type number can't has `id` property and it will give an error, that's why there is checking if it is number assign number, if else it is type of `Hero` assign `hero.id`